# How to get category slug link? ( include parent categories)

Tags: categories, permalinks, links, slug

for example,
 if main category slug is **cars**;
 sub-category slug is: **Ford**;
how to get the permalink of **Ford**, including its parent categories' slug?
( `get_category_link()` returns `mysite.com/?cat=19` type of link,
 but i want `mysite.com/cars/ford` )

Answer (score -1):

my solution:

```
$catid='24'
$cats = get_category ($catid);
if ($cats) 
    {$category_link = $cats->slug;
        if ( $parent = $cats->parent )
            {
            $category_link = get_category_parents($parent, false, '/', true) . $category_link;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer. This question keeps on rotating as unresolved.

Comment: Also, please post a proper solution with proper explanation with what your code does